# Linux downloading a file appending to file

Tags: linux, terminal

So I'm downloading a file and getting the data from the download, not actually storing the file itself.

Just want to see the speeds and log them.

```
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log.log -O /dev/null &
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log.log -O /dev/null &
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log.log -O /dev/null
```

I am trying to download simultaneously but the output is overlapping, how do I prevent this?

Comment: Yeah was thinking of doing that but that's a little hacky, there no preset way to do it? @洋葱头

Comment: I don't think there is a way to determine the order of writing. But I'm also not an expert in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could first write your output to different files and then merge them together.
This should work:

```
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log1.log &
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log2.log &
wget http://www.google.com/download -a log3.log ;
cat log2.log >> log1.log;
cat log3.log >> log1.log
```

Now you should have all your output in `log1.log`

Answer (score 0):

if you want with append command is ok. if you dont want append just overwrite change -a command to  -o

```
wget http://www.google.com/download  -o log.log -O /dev/null
```